# Some big files are getting corrupted - is my HDD failing?

Tags: hard-drive, disk

I downloaded Mathematica (5gb+ installation file) and when I tried to reinstall it after a few months, it said checksum does not match. I downloaded it again and reinstalled it. The next day I copied the installation file to another partition and tried to reinstall it (to check if I get the same error), and now it again says checksum does not match. I saw that the checksum of some of the large files (.iso files of distros) do not match as well.

Also, almost once every month or so, the desktop fails to load and goes into `busybox` prompt, so I would have to run `fdisk /dev/sda3` to fix it. Is this a sign that my HDD is going to fail soon?

My laptop is 3 years old, but I have used it almost every day. I am running Ubuntu 18.04.

Here is the result of `sudo smartctl --a /dev/sda`, but I don't know how to interpret it.

```
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-5.3.0-46-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Toshiba 2.5" HDD MQ01ABD...
Device Model:     TOSHIBA MQ01ABD100
Serial Number:    27Q7TGAHT
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 79130b74c
Firmware Version: AX1R4C
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Apr 14 12:34:19 2020 IST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x80) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (  25) The self-test routine was aborted by
                                        the host.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:                (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x51) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        No Auto Offline data collection support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        No Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 199) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0027   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0023   100   100   002    Pre-fail  Always       -       1733
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4566
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002f   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0025   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   089   089   000    Old_age   Always       -       4608
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0033   190   100   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3621
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0033   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
185 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       65535
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       4
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   061   054   040    Old_age   Always       -       39 (Min/Max 37/39)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       133
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       6160478
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       41568
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   061   054   040    Old_age   Always       -       39 (Min/Max 37/39)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%      4608         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

What do the value, worst, threshold and raw_value mean?

Comment: Your drive's SMART counters look ok so far. Nevertheless you should show the full output of `smartctl -a /dev/sda` and you should also run a SMART check on your drive `smartctl -t long /dev/sda`. My current guess is you have a problem with your file system. Try to run a Live Linux (from USB or CD) and run `fsck -f` on your hard drive's partitions.

Comment: The long command will take some time. I have posted the other output.